# JavaScript arrays checking

Tags: javascript, arrays, dialog, prompt

I'm going to have unknown number of prompt dialogs.
I will have their number after some user actions, but I want to create them, display them and at the end check if some of them is `null(empty)`.
I'm looking for ideas how to do that.
Can I do it without loop?
Something like:

```
arrayName[] = prompt("Enter text");
arrayName[] = prompt("Enter text");
arrayName[] = prompt("Enter text");
arrayName[] = prompt("Enter text");
```

and then check if some of them is empty?
And can I declare array in shorthand way like in PHP and C#?

```
array[]
array[]
```

Comment: *"Can I do it without loop?"* Why would you want to? This is what loops are *for*.

Comment: How do you define how many prompts have to be defined?

Comment: is it a value passed from the server? or a count calculated at the client side or decided based on a value entered by the user in one of the prompts

Comment: Nope. The value is typed by the user. I wanted to escape the loop, because I have to send an AJAX request to the server for each prompt in the array and I just wanted to ignore the empty prompts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can and you can use =[] to create the array

```
var arrayName=[];
arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));
arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));
arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));
arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));
arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));

for (var i=0;i<arrayNames.length;i++) {
  if (arrayName[i]==null) alert("You did not answer "+(i+1))
}
```

If you can use a loop it is of course simpler. Please tell use why you do not want to use a loop?

```
var arrayName=[];
for (var i=0;i<unknownNumberOfPrompts;i++) {
  var answer = prompt("Enter text","");
  if (answer) arrayName.push(answer);
}
if (arrayname.length>0) {
  // something was answered
}
```

Comment: *"I'm going to have **unknown** number of prompt dialogs."* (my emphasis)

Comment: Yes, my code will check any number of prompts assuming each prompt is specified as `arrayName.push(prompt("Enter text"));`

Comment: But again, it's an ***unknown*** number. So clearly they can't just be written in the source; that would be *known*. (He also asked to do this "without loop" for some completely unknown reason...) Anyway, I leave you and the OP to it. If the question ever makes sense, he's in good hands getting it answered. :-)

Comment: I will create a loop and it will set the correct number of arrays.

Comment: It may be unknown to the script at the time of writing and receive an unknown number of prompts from a cfout or php echo or whatever